# How does one explain Calculon's popularity?

Tags: futurama

I've seen Calculon in so many different avatars (singer, actor, director, romantic interest etc), and in all of these different roles, he seems rather hammy to me. However, he seems to retain his astonishing popularity among the different folks on Futurama. How does one explain Calculon's popularity?

Comment: He's the William Shatner of the 31st century.

Comment: Robots are programmed to like him.

Answer (score 10):

He gained his "unholy acting talent" after making a deal with the [Robot Devil](http://theinfosphere.org/Robot_Devil), as explained in the episode ["The Devil's Hands Are Idle Playthings"](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Devil%27s_Hands_Are_Idle_Playthings). It would appear from our point of view that the devil didn't so much give him acting talent as he did the *illusion* of acting talent by simply making him inexplicably popular as an entertainer.

Answer (score 7):

**Look at [Calculon](http://theinfosphere.org/Calculon) the same way you would look at any actor who has amazing popularity but you find yourself wondering exactly HOW they got famous. Humans with the same power include Tom Cruise, Nicolas Cage or Keanu Reeves. You know they ARE famous, but you cannot understand how they got that way. It's hard to remember them acting in anything you enjoyed recenty. In the Futurama universe, Calculon is that acting unit.**

Part of his popularity is his programming. Calculon is scandalous off-camera as well as on-camera, only adding to his robot charm and appeal. With his thousand years of acting experience, as many of the famous robot actors of the past, he may not be very good, but he has plenty of experience knowing what robots want to see and is good at giving them what they want. Prone to being a bit melodramatic, Calculon does not ever seem to NOT be acting. His last attempt at directing ended in disaster, literally.

Calculon's role in the famous soap opera "[**All My Circuits**](http://theinfosphere.org/All_My_Circuits)" is popular with robots and humans alike. And like many soap opera stars, no one can tell you why they like them, only that they do. The acting's hammy, the storylines convoluted, but all the robots are beautiful and all their behavior is reprehensible, just like any respectable human soap opera.

Comment: Tom Cruise, despite his crazyness off camera, is actually a pretty good actor.

Comment: Ehm "It's hard to remember them in **anything that you like**." *plus* "include Tom Cruise, Nicolas Cage or **Keanu Reeves**" ... I'm confused

Comment: RE: Tom Cruise - everyone I know simply can't stand him. They can't tell you what it is, only that between his onscreen personas and off-screen behavior, he is the last person on Earth they would want to be trapped with in an elevator. I don't quite loathe him that way, but he always seemed a little squirrelly and off-balanced to me...

Answer (score 0):

I simply see him as the 008 of robots 
He's smooth and self assured; as well as being on the most popular (next to hypno toad and Iron chef) robo-tv-show of the day.
A she bot might say no -BUT- will end up saying yes when propositioned by this suave hunk of steel.
Why not everybody can be a Bender...
The true Robo - 007
Just a thought :)